# Storing a (complex) MongoDB query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection of documents, each document representing a *fish*.
Users of my application can then define a *type of fish*, by creating a query on the fish collection.  This query can be very complex, using [Conditional Operators](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-ConditionalOperators), etc.

For example, a user could define the 
'highly abnormal shark-like fish'
to be any fish returned by:

```
{'length':{$gte : 45}, 'name' : {$in : ['Klaus', 'Alistair', 'Steve']}}
```

But new fish are frequently being discovered, and I need to assign types to them based on the queries created by the users. That is, I will need to use this query again many times in the future.  Therefore, my thought is to have a collection with documents like this:

```
{'typename' : 'highly abnormal shark-like fish', 
'query' : '{'length':{$gte : 45}, 'name' : {$in : ['Klaus', 'Alistair', 'Steve']}}'}
```

My question is: should I store the query as a string?  Is that the best way?

Please keep in mind that as new fish are discovered,  I will have to *apply* the query using the PHP driver.  Should I store the PHP-array-version of the query as a string, then use eval()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If users build the queries as an input string, sure, store that. You want them to be able to edit it later. But then you already do `eval`, don't you?

Otherwise serialize the query document and store that.

Comment: The users build the query in a form; they don't know what's going on behind the scenes.  I build the query from their form inputs, so no, I'm not doing an eval() currently.

Comment: for `eval` you have to store with `array(`, which will look just as ugly as the serialized value, so use the latter one.

Comment: thanks!  I did not know about serialize(), it does exactly what I wanted.